# Cannot compute SHA-512 with DigestUtils

Tags: java, eclipse, hash, apache-commons-codec

I have a function to compute SHA-512 digest.

```
public Hash hash(byte[] data) {
    return new Hash(org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha512(data));
    }
```

It gives me the following error

> The method sha512(byte[]) is undefined for the type DigestUtils

Moreover, using `sha512Hex()` instead of `sha512()` gives me the same error. I have tried

```
import static org.apache.commons.codec.digest.MessageDigestAlgorithms.SHA_512;
```

But no use. The only options I seem to have are these:

[image]

Also, I have tried methods from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html as well, but nothing seems to work.

I am using jdk-11.0.2, and everything else works perfectly fine.

Comment: What version of Apache commons do you use?

Comment: I'm sorry, how do you check the version? @JohannesKuhn

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I have used commons-codec-1.2 and commons-codec-1.9 but neither is working.

Comment: According to the documentation it is in 1.9. 1.2 is so old I can't even find the release anywhere, and was probably released before SHA512 was even invented.

Comment: I have figured out that 1.10 was compatible with it. I had spent more than 3 days but I couldn't figure it out. This version thing has done the job. Thank you for giving me the hint.